# Regex: Performing string replacement with same pattern but with different replacement words

Tags: java, regex, string

My regular expression pattern is as follows:

```
public final static String REGEX_PATTERN = "\\bTRS[S|P|M]....\\b";
```

So for a test string such as this:

```
"Hey there! I think TRSS190E is a very important parameter for the rover. Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSP1143 and TRSM0146 for it's platform and mobility subsystems."
```

I **expect** this string to return:

```
"Hey there! I think TRST0822 is a very important parameter for the rover. Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSP6644 and TRSM1273 for it's platform and mobility subsystems."
```

However my implementation is replacing every matching word in the string with the *same* replacement. I.e:

```
Hey there! I think TRST0822 is a very important parameter for the rover. Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRST0822 and TRST0822 for it's platform and mobility subsystems.
```

Test code is as follows:

```
@Test
    public void performRegexReplacement() {
        // Construct a test mapper/dictionary
        List<aMap> aMaps = new ArrayList<aMap>();
        aMaps.add(new aMap(new String[] {"TRSS190E", "TRST0822"}));
        aMaps.add(new aMap(new String[] {"TRSP1143", "TRSP6644"}));
        aMaps.add(new aMap(new String[] {"TRSM0146", "TRSM1273"}));
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper(aMaps);

        // Perform replacement
        String corpus = "Hey there! I think TRSS190E is a very important parameter for the rover. " +
                "Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSP1143 and TRSM0146 for it's " +
                "platform and mobility subsystems.";

        String expectedCorpus = "Hey there! I think TRST0822 is a very important parameter for the rover. " +
                "Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSP6644 and TRSM1273 for it's " +
                "platform and mobility subsystems.";
        String[] find = new String[] {"TRSS190E", "TRSP1143", "TRSM0146"};

        List<String> matchingTargets = StringUtils.getPatternMatchingWords(corpus);

        System.out.println("matchingTargets: "+matchingTargets.toString());

        List<String> replacements = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String matchingTarget : matchingTargets) {
            // search mapper for replacement str
            replacements.add(mapper.linearSearch(matchingTarget));
        }

        System.out.println("replacements: "+replacements.toString());

        String updatedCorpus = StringUtils.replaceWords(corpus, matchingTargets, replacements);
        assertEquals(expectedCorpus, updatedCorpus);    
    }
```

String utility methods:

```
public static List<String> getPatternMatchingWords(String text) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        List<String> matchedWords = new ArrayList<>();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String fullMatch = matcher.group(0);
            matchedWords.add(fullMatch);
        }
        return matchedWords;
    }


public static String replaceWords(String text, List<String> targets, List<String> replacements) {
//      StringBuilder sb = null;
        System.out.println("targets: "+targets.toString());

        int i = 0;
        String str = null;
        for(String target : targets) {
            str = replaceWord(text, target, replacements.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }

/**
     * Replaces all instances of a matching word in text.
     * @param text
     * @param target
     * @param replacement
     * @return  <code>String</code> containing replacement(s)
     */
    public static String replaceWord(CharSequence text, String target, String replacement) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()) { 
            String txt = matcher.group(0);
           matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);

        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Console output:

```
matchingTargets: [TRSS190E, TRSP1143, TRSM0146]
replacements: [TRST0822, TRSP6644, TRSM1273]
targets: [TRSS190E, TRSP1143, TRSM0146]
Hey there! I think TRST0822 is a very important parameter for the rover. Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRST0822 and TRST0822 for it's platform and mobility subsystems.
Hey there! I think TRSP6644 is a very important parameter for the rover. Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSP6644 and TRSP6644 for it's platform and mobility subsystems.
Hey there! I think TRSM1273 is a very important parameter for the rover. Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSM1273 and TRSM1273 for it's platform and mobility subsystems.
Hey there! I think TRSM1273 is a very important parameter for the rover. Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSM1273 and TRSM1273 for it's platform and mobility subsystems.
```

Comment: what difference between the first String and the 2ed? what you want to do with that pattern ?

Comment: I'm still a newbie to regex so perhaps I might've got the pattern wrong. But basically I have a dictionary (Key->Value) / (targets -> replacements) and I wish to replace key with value. Some sample data: {(TRSP3058 ->TRSG0013),
(TRSP309E -> TRSG0014),
(TRSP30BC ->TRSG0015)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to replace certain words by others.

I'd suggest you to put all of the words and their replacement in the same Map and run the following :

```
public static String replaceWords(String text, Map<String,String> replacement) {
    String temp = text;

    for(Entry<String,String> entry : replacement.entrySet()){
        temp = temp.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return temp;
}
```

No need for REGEX (at least, not that you see) if you want to replace the litteral Strings.

EDIT :

Using the above function, your test case (but without junit) :

```
public static void performRegexReplacement() {
    // Construct a test mapper/dictionary
    List<Map<String, String>> dictionnary = Arrays.asList(Collections.singletonMap("TRSS190E", "TRST0822"), Collections.singletonMap("TRSP1143", "TRSP6644"), Collections.singletonMap("TRSM0146", "TRSM1273"));

    // Perform replacement
    String corpus = "Hey there! I think TRSS190E is a very important parameter for the rover. " +
            "Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSP1143 and TRSM0146 for it's " +
            "platform and mobility subsystems.";

    String expectedCorpus = "Hey there! I think TRST0822 is a very important parameter for the rover. " +
            "Because the Martian atmosphere also requires TRSP6644 and TRSM1273 for it's " +
            "platform and mobility subsystems.";

    String updatedCorpus = corpus;
    for(Map<String,String> replacement : dictionnary){
        updatedCorpus = replaceWords(updatedCorpus, replacement);
    }

    System.out.println(updatedCorpus);

    if(expectedCorpus.equals(updatedCorpus)){
        System.out.println("yay");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `Map` is not an option as I have some mapping as follows: { ([TRSS4790]->[TRSS4451]),
([TRSS4451]->[TRST2792])} A `Map` will complain about duplication of K/V and throw an exception.

Comment: Ah Ok. Then iterate over a list of Maps.

Comment: I'm basically doing the equivalent of that if you look at the top 5 lines of my test method `performRegexReplacement`

Comment: You could also simply create a List of Entry<String,String> and iterate over it once. the String.replace(original,replacement) method is enough for what you do. No need for you to use any REGEX.